# How do I prevent Mobile Safari from cropping out the bottom of a web page?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm currently working on a temporary "under construction" page for my website, where the content would scroll within a full-height box on the `body` element set in 100vh surrounded by margins to give a "page border"-like effect.

However, when testing on Mobile Safari, I find that the bottom border of the page got cropped out, and the main `body` element would end up being scrollable instead of only the content wrapper within.

How do I get the bottom area of the site to appear within Mobile Safari's viewport?

[image]

Comment: Any CSS to share ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got to mention something in the css file about different screen sizes. Try adding this,

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
body {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

}

This might work!

Answer (score -2):

I HIGHLY recommend familiarizing yourself with bootstrap: https://getbootstrap.com/. If you refer to this site here: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/ you can adjust the screen sizes and how they fit according to each device. It will also make everything dynamic which is a huge timesaver. If you search online "bootstrap footers (or anything else) you can import code and change it for your liking.

Also, be sure to write the following line in your header in order to import the bootstrap libraries if this is the route you are choosing to take:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" 
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
integrity="sha384-
BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" 
crossorigin="anonymous">
```

That link is for the CSS libraries. If you need the JavaScript libraries refer to my first link.

Comment: This answer is entirely unrelated.